# I want to Update Sql Server Database How to add columns or table in SQL Server database threw a VB.net Application

Tags: vb.net-2010

[I want to Update Sql Server Database How to add columns or table in SQL Server  database threw a VB.net Application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mebh2.png) ? when i Update in SQL Server its run Perfectly but when i install on another Computer Its Shown Error"Invalid Field "+Updated Field Name Please Help

Comment: Make sure you pointed towards the same SQL Server even you installed on another machine. `ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD column_name datatype;` To add the columns you need

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2005 onwards:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.columns 
          WHERE Name = N'columnName'
          AND Object_ID = Object_ID(N'schemaName.tableName'))
BEGIN
    -- Column Exists
END



IF COL_LENGTH('schemaName.tableName', 'columnName') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    -- Column Exists
END
```